# Make a dark mode with nextJS without any dependences

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I created a website with **Next JS** and I Add an icon of light and dark mode like that in `Navbar.js`.

```html
<FontAwesomeIcon onClick={darkMode} icon={click ? faSun : faMoon} className="icon"/>
```

and this is the function that change the icon.

```js
const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

const darkMode = (event) => {
        setClick(!click)
}
```

and I create `useState` for the dark theme.

```js
const [dark, setDark] = useState(undefined)
```

and then I got stuck!!

I tried to find out about it and I found https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document but it say that i can't make `onClick`.

I want to know how to change `body` className from `light` to `dark` and vice verse in order to make the dark mode effect.

How can I do this?

**Note :** I don't want to add any packages or make it in component function, just with `useState` or `useEffect` or both.

Comment: `_document` is not very suitable for that problem, try with `_app`

Comment: You can try [css vars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66829464/2873538).