# React | How to select CSS file to use

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web-deployment

I am creating a page which will have both light mode and dark mode.
I have added both the buttons, and have created two different CSS spreadsheets, one for dark mode and one for light mode. I am currently using the light mode CSS file as I imported it at the beginning, however I am unsure how to select a different CSS file to be used.
If anyone knows a solution I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386125/dynamically-load-a-stylesheet-with-react

Comment: You can try this alternative: [How to achieve dark/light themes in a React App?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66829464/2873538)