# Getting the true value of a CSS variable

Tags: css, sass

When you assign a CSS `var()` variable to an Sass variable like this:

```
--color: #FFF;
$color: var(--color);
```

This will result in `$color` holding the `var(--color)` as a value. Is there a way so it would hold the actual CSS `#FFF` value? So `$color` would save the `#FFF` instead of `var(--color)`?

This would be great so you can use the css variables in more complex functions and media queries where var() isn't allowed.

Comment: no you cannot ...

Comment: Maybe this answer, to a similar question, helps. [Any way to use CSS Variables in SASS functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70672476)

Comment: You could do the opposite way. You would create sass variables with fixed value, and convert them to custom properties through a mixin. Would that be ok for you ?

Comment: The framework uses css variables to overwrite. But for each color  there is always a second variable with the RGB numbers as value. So it's a little bit of housekeeping, but it does allow to use it in Sass variables, functions and rgba() notations. So this is a good solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible directly, but an alternative is to keep the rgb or hsl value instead of a hex value.

```
--color: 129, 19, 29;
$color: rgb(var(--color));
```

You could specify 2 variables for each like below, to have both options available.

```
--color: #554784;
--color-rgb: 129, 19, 29;
```

Or just always use the rgb(a) notation

```
color: rgb(var(--color));
```