# How to use @property CSS variable inside SCSS

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have been struggling with how to use --rotate value from this CSS code inside my **Angular** SCSS code

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/gayane-gasparyan/pen/jOmaBQK

```css
@property --rotate {
  syntax: "<angle>";
  initial-value: 132deg;
  inherits: false;
}

.card::before {
  content: "";
  width: 104%;
  height: 102%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    var(--rotate)
    , #5ddcff, #3c67e3 43%, #4e00c2);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -1%;
    left: -2%;
    animation: spin 2.5s linear infinite;
}
```

I have tried this answer but not working.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70672476/4591364

may I get some help, please?

Comment: Cool effect. Anyway, you mean use css variable from styles.css in another file styles.scss?

Comment: @JoosepParts yes...

Comment: Using `@import` from a shared file didn't work?

Comment: @JoosepParts this trick didn't work

Comment: Are you sure your files are loaded in the correct order? Answer listed in your question works for me..